# Saving in two tables from one form / first implementation - no insertion / second - no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, nested-attributes

I want to insert into two database tables by clicking on a button. And there are several problems:

First Problem:

**Models:**

```
class Dish < ApplicationRecord   
has_many :courses   
has_many :days, through: :courses   
has_many :order_items   
accepts_nested_attributes_for :courses 
end
```

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord   
belongs_to :day   
belongs_to :dish 
end
```

**Controller:**

```
class DishesController < ApplicationController    
def new     
@dish = Dish.new     
@dish.courses.build   
end    

def create
     @dish = Dish.new(dish_params)
     if @dish.save 
      redirect_to '/dashboard' 
    else 
      render 'new' 
    end 
  end  
 
 private def dish_params  
   params.require(:dish).permit(:id, :name, :description, :price, courses_attributes: [:id, :name])
   end
  end
```

**Views:**

```
<div class="new dish"> 
  <%= form_for @dish do |d|  %> 
  <%= d.text_field :name, :placeholder => "Dish name" %>
   <%= d.text_area :description, :placeholder => "Description" %> 
  <%= d.text_field :price, :placeholder => "Dish price" %>
   <%= d.fields_for :courses do |c| %> 
      <%= c.text_field :name, :placeholder => "Course name" %> 
  <%= d.submit "Save" %>
</div> 
<% end %> 
<% end %>
```

After pressing the Save button, there is no insertion into the database. no redirection to '/ dashboard' occurs, the form is rendered as written in the controller. Here is the log:

```
Processing by DishesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"fNbaoB4w+OINn17HQ0CdwAothP8PTzR7XPYy4oy5kHpFiCUOXY4T2hOFMbrmObXFaVdI6R1jPE2/K+piXPvymQ==", "dish"=>{"name"=>"aa", "description"=>"aaa", "price"=>"1", "courses_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"main course"}}}, "commit"=>"Save"}
  Rendering dishes/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered dishes/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 2.2ms | Allocations: 464)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
Completed 200 OK in 32ms (Views: 21.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 6607)
```

**If I change the view to:**

```
<div class="new dish"> 
  <%= form_for @dish do |d|  %> 
  <%= d.text_field :name, :placeholder => "Dish name" %> 
  <%= d.text_area :description, :placeholder => "Description" %> 
  <%= d.text_field :price, :placeholder => "Dish price" %>
   <%= d.fields_for :courses_attributes do |c| %>
       <%= c.text_field :name, :placeholder => "Course name" %>
   <%= d.submit "Save" %>
 </div> 
<% end %> 
<% end %>
```

**then I get**

TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):
app/controllers/dishes_controller.rb:9:in `create'

And here is a log:

```
Processing by DishesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"jE7DMuPcyEo403MKrxjO2KySlM3cA/t9ZjGYNnAUlAu1EDycoGIjcibJHHcKYebdz+hY284v80uF7EC2oFb26A==", "dish"=>{"name"=>"xxx", "description"=>"tt", "price"=>"1", "courses_attributes"=>{"name"=>"first course"}}, "commit"=>"Save"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 934)
```

The second problem is at the level of theory and I have not yet begun to solve it.
I do not yet understand how, without filling the form with values after clicking the button, throw the dish_id and day_id attribute values into the courses table. In the course table, I have several columns:
dish_id, day_id, name.

May you help me please? Why there is no insert into two tables in first problem?

Comment: From the code you have right now, it seems like the first version doesn't get saved because the `day_id` is missing for the course. `belongs_to` has a presence validation and since you're not passing a day id it is not valid (or if you have any other validations that you have not posted yet) . You can verify if you change `.save` to `.save!`. it'll throw an error

Comment: @Clara, thank you. I'll try to pass day_id